# Rerendering components in React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a problem because my component keeps rerendering while I'm toggling it.
I have an arrow(up/down) that will show/hide a part of the div.

I wrote `console.log('render')` to see if its rerendering. I'm only toggling one div at a time but it is rerendering multiples times. How do I fix this?

CODESANDBOX --------> [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/complete-autocomplete-productimages-snt6o?file=/src/components/ProductCard/index.js)

```
  const toggleArrow = (
    <IconButton
      aria-label="delete"
      size="large"
      onClick={() => {
        handleProductCard(productIndex);
        productCardRef.current.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: "smooth"
        });
      }}
      sx={{ padding: 0 }}
    >
      {formik.values.hideProductCard ? (
        <KeyboardArrowDownIcon size="large" />
      ) : (
        <KeyboardArrowUpIcon size="large" />
      )}
    </IconButton>
  );
```

Comment: Can you helpme understand why your component rerendering 4 times is a problem?

Comment: https://www.developerway.com/posts/react-re-renders-guide

Comment: @SharanBalakrishnan. How do I optimize this? Imagine if i have several rows of images. it will rerender a lot of times

Comment: I don't notice any overt rendering issues with the code. When I toggle a section I see the entire list render again, and only 1 additional rerender of the item that was *just* toggled. I don't think this is a problem. Make sure any console logs you have are placed into a `useEffect` hook so you only see the logs when the component is rendered/rerendered to the DOM.

Comment: @DrewReese. So I have multiple rows of products, let's say 100. I notice that there's some delay when toggling it, like it will wait for several seconds to expand/close. But if there are few rows only like the one currently, its quite faster. Any workaround to make it fast even on hundreds of rows?